# ArrayList does not send all elements as datasource for ireport

Tags: java, arraylist, jasper-reports

Only the last two elements of my ArrayList are sent as datasource in ireport. I have an ArrayList that stores data read from tags in xml files. For example, I select three xml files with the same tags but with different data. I have a method that reads these files and will filling an ArrayList, but when I send pro ireport only the last two are the last data xml are displayed.

Code that allows you to select the files and sends them to read, after reading a list is returned and I pass the list as datasource:

```
 private void btnPegarArquivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
// TODO add your handling code here:
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
// Possibilita a seleção de vários arquivos
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

// Apresenta a caixa de diálogo
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

// Retorna os arquivos selecionados. Este método retorna vazio se
// o modo de múltipla seleção de arquivos não estiver ativada.
File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();

for (File argumento : files) {
   System.err.println("Argumentos: " + argumento.getPath());
    caminho = argumento.getPath();
    LeitorXMLDOMMelhorado parser = new LeitorXMLDOMMelhorado();

    try {
        /* List<Cliente> */
        listaContatos = (ArrayList<Cliente>) parser.realizaLeituraXML(caminho);
        System.out.println("Valores: " + listaContatos);


        for(Cliente c : listaContatos){ 
            System.out.println("Nome no Arquivo xml: "+c.getNome());
            gerarRelatorio((ArrayList) listaContatos);
        } 
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("O parser não foi configurado corretamente.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("Problema ao fazer o parse do arquivo.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("O arquivo não pode ser lido.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


}
```

Method that generates the report:

```
public void gerarRelatorio(ArrayList list) {
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {

    JasperReport report = null;

    try {
        InputStream inputStreamReal = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/testexml/relatorio/Teste.jrxml");
        report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStreamReal);

    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TesteView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print,
                "C:\\relatorios/RelatorioClientes" + i + ".pdf");

    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TesteView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
}
```

Class that reads the xml and populates a list:

```
public class LeitorXMLDOMMelhorado {

public List<Cliente> realizaLeituraXML(String arquivoXML) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    //fazer o parse do arquivo e criar o documento XML
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(arquivoXML);

    //Passo 1: obter o elemento raiz
    Element raiz = doc.getDocumentElement();
    System.out.println("O elemento raiz é: " + raiz.getNodeName());

    //Passo 2: localizar os elementos filhos da agenda
    NodeList listaContatos = raiz.getElementsByTagName("contato");

    List<Cliente> lista = new ArrayList<Cliente>(listaContatos.getLength());

    //Passo 3: obter os elementos de cada elemento contato
    for (int i = 0; i < listaContatos.getLength(); i++) {

        //como cada elemento do NodeList é um nó, precisamos fazer o cast
        Element elementoContato = (Element) listaContatos.item(i);

        //cria um objeto Contato com as informações do elemento contato
        Cliente contato = criaContato(elementoContato);
        lista.add(contato);
        //System.err.println("Listaaaaaaa: " + lista);

        // System.err.println("Lista no metodo:"+lista);

    }
    return lista;
}
```

Comment: Please cut down your code to the significant lines, where your problem occurs. Even if they might be able to solve your problem, people don't like to fight their way through your scourcecode.

Comment: Could you add a debug line just before you instantiate JasperPrint?  Do something like JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list); System.out.println(ds.getRecordCount());  Then show us the output.

Comment: My report is thus:
http://i.imgur.com/0Bw2Csl.png

Comment: And this debug line   `System.out.println("Nome no Arquivo xml: " + c.getNome());` Returned: [link](http://i.imgur.com/27MNRWQ.png)